# Tkinter: keep update a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I really need help, my brain is melting because of this problem. I've studied python for 2 months maybe and I'm not very expert in programming. I've got an issue... I'm using tkinter on this program; in this small GUI I'd like to always keep updated the global variable "temp", and its value should change everytime I click on the button. I know that mainloop() is a blocking method, so it is possible to do something like this?

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = tk.Tk()
    self.screen.geometry("400x400")
    self.screen.title("Modifica temperatura ambiente")
    self.screen.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    self.label = tk.Label(self.screen, text="ENTER TEMPERATUR VALUE", fg = "black", font = ("Calibri", 10) )
    self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "N", pady = 10)

    self.input_ = tk.Entry(self.screen)
    self.input_.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "WE", pady = 5, padx = 20)

    self.button = tk.Button(self.screen, text = "INVIA", command = self.getvalue)
    self.button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "WE", pady = 5, padx = 10)

def getvalue(self):
    self.temp = self.input_.get()
    temperatura_label = tk.Label(self.screen, text = "Last input value is " + self.temp + " degrees", fg = "red")
    temperatura_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "S")
    return self.temp

app = App()
temp = app.getvalue()
print(temp)
app.screen.mainloop()
```

Thank for the help!

Comment: Okay listen.. When I run it and I click the button, it only prints the value on the GUI in the red line, but not on the terminal. What does it happen to you? I'm using visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print it in the terminal, modify your `getvalue` function.

Code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

screen = tk.Tk()
screen.geometry("400x400")
screen.title("Modifica temperatura ambiente")
screen.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.label = tk.Label(master, text="ENTER TEMPERATUR VALUE", fg = "black", font = ("Calibri", 10) )
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "N", pady = 10)

        self.input_ = tk.Entry(master)
        self.input_.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "WE", pady = 5, padx = 20)


    def getvalue(self):
        self.temp = self.input_.get()
        temperatura_label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Last input value is " + self.temp + " degrees", fg = "red")
        temperatura_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "S")
        if self.temp == None:
            print()
        else:
            return self.temp

app = App(screen)

def main_loop():
    global app
    temp = app.getvalue()
    print(temp)


button = tk.Button(screen, text = "INVIA", command = main_loop)
button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "WE", pady = 5, padx = 10)



screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: So is it not possible to print "temp" from outside the class?

Comment: @RaoulFiorentini Well, if you mean you want to put the temp outside the class, then it will only print once. After that, the program will only loop inside the class, meaning it won't work. Sorry if that is an inconvenience to you.

Comment: @RaoulFiorentini Also, please don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Not really helpful but you're kind. :) I've a question for you. I wanted the temp outside the class because i need that variable to put it in a json and that send it to a server using mqtt protocol. Any idea to deceive this problem?

Comment: Okay, I think I have an idea, stay on line @RaoulFiorentini

Comment: here in italy is 2 am. I'm really tired ahha

Comment: @RaoulFiorentini Check back tommorow then :)

Comment: @RaoulFiorentini Done.

Comment: OMG! Wonderful!!! Thank you very much!!!! I'm gonna learn this solution!!!